# SQL Trigger Creates Duplicates Of Records?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to implement a trigger to log changes in a payment table into a payment audit table.

I'm trying to run a simple insert query - every time a new payment is inserted into the payments table, a copy of it will be made in the payments_history table.

For some reason I can't understand, the trigger will create multiple copies of the record in my audit table, instead of just one.

I'm new to sql and have been trying to figure this out for hours.

This is my audit table...

```
      -- AUDIT TABLE -- 
CREATE TABLE Payment_History(
    paymenthistoryid SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, -- synthetic primary key 
    memberid INT NOT NULL,  -- FK reference
    paymentid INT NOT NULL, -- FK reference
    amountpaid varchar(300),-- old payment amount
    amountpaid_new varchar(300), -- new payment amount
    amountpaiddate timestamp, -- old payment date
    amountpaiddate_new timestamp,  -- new payment date
    amountpaiduntildate timestamp, -- old paiduntildate
    amountpaiduntildate_new timestamp, -- new paiduntildate
    changetype varchar(1), -- was it an insert, update or delete
    time_stamp timestamp,
    FOREIGN KEY (memberid)
        REFERENCES member (memberid)
);
```

And this is my trigger...

```
CREATE FUNCTION audit()
    RETURNS TRIGGER
    LANGUAGE PLPGSQL
    AS
$$
BEGIN                       
        INSERT INTO payment_history (memberid, paymentid, amountpaid, amountpaiddate, amountpaiduntildate, changetype, time_stamp)
        SELECT NEW.memberid, NEW.paymentid, NEW.amountpaid, NEW.amountpaiddate, NEW.amountpaiduntildate, 'I', now();
        RETURN NEW;
                                        
END;
$$

CREATE TRIGGER audit_table
BEFORE INSERT ON payment
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE audit(); 

INSERT INTO payment (paymentid, memberid, amountpaid, amountpaiddate, amountpaiduntildate)
VALUES (3,2,20.00, '2023-03-17 00:00:00', '2023-02-17 00:00:00')
```

My output looks like this

```
8   2   3   "20.00"     "2023-03-17 00:00:00"       "2023-02-17 00:00:00"       "I" "2023-02-25 20:10:44.989859"
9   2   3   "20.00"     "2023-03-17 00:00:00"       "2023-02-17 00:00:00"           
10  2   3   "20.00"     "2023-03-17 00:00:00"       "2023-02-17 00:00:00"
```

Where it seems like 2 extra rows have been added.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: i can't reproduce it https://dbfiddle.uk/UpjqdH7l

Comment: just tried running it again in postgresql using your code - it created a duplicate for me again

Comment: restart the computer, as you see in the fiddle it works just fine, or you have maybe more than trigger see https://database.guide/3-ways-to-list-all-triggers-for-a-given-table-in-postgresql/

Comment: you're right, there was a trigger firing that i wasn't aware of - thanks for your help.